# memory corruption after structure copy

Tags: c++11, memory-leaks, memory-corruption

Note:  Following code is causing memory corruption in process function input req is assigned to rsp. I didn't understand what happened here. after removing "rsp = req" then it is working. does this assignment will cause shallow copy of the structures in req?
does req and rsp structures are pointing same memory here?

```
    struct info
    {
       uint8_t                     id;
       uint64_t                    post_id;
       uint64_t                    time_id;
    };

     struct updates
     {
       uint32_t                  id;
       uint32_t                  fcn;
       uint16_t                  icp;
       uint64_t                  num_oh;
       uint64_t                  num_rna;
       bool                      is_rbn;
    };

    
     struct rbn_rel_info
     {
        uint16_t                    icp;
        uint32_t                    fcn;
        info               relation;
        uint32_t                     id_length;
        uint32_t                     id;
     };

    struct rbn_info
     {
        uint16_t                  icp;
        uint32_t                  fcn;
     };

   struct ind_info
    {
       info           _info;
              
       uint16_t       num_rbn;
       rbn_info       _rbn_info[32];
       
       uint16_t       num_rel;
       rbn_rel_info   rel[32];
       
       uint8_t          nums;
       updates     _updates[32];
    };

void process(struct ind_info req)
{
    struct ind_info rsp = req;
    //process req and send rsp
    send_rsp(rsp);
}
    
int main()
{
    
   struct ind_info req = {};
    process(req);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From this code I cannot see how a memory corruption could occur. The argument is passed by value and cannot corrupt any memory. There are no pointers in the structures either. The assignment as well, both use the compiler generated [Trivial copy assignment operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_assignment).

The only reason I can think of is that something funny happens in `send_rsp` but I can't tell without looking at the code.